# Slide out from right on hover, slide in from left on mouse out

Tags: css, css-transitions, keyframe

http://jsfiddle.net/vladimir_ze/ror4ccry/

I'm trying to achieve two sliding effects using CSS.

- On hover, arrow should slide out of the box (moving right), that's
  not problem.
- On mouse leave, arrow should slide in to the box (from left)

I tried to do it with transitions but I'm not sure if this can be done like that, if its not, is it possible to make it with keyframes?

```
.arrow {
        width: 30px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

i.fa {
    font-size:50px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
}

.arrow:hover i {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}


<div class="arrow">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Doubtful you could so this with transitions because they alternate between **states** and these would not be the same. An animation **might** be possible but it might take some thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/ror4ccry/5/)

This is a bit tricky to get done.

- Added `animation` to be played on start only 1 time.
- on hover play transition (or animation)
- If you use a transition on the hover set the animation to be none:
  What this does is reset the animation and then plays it again when you remove the cursor, because it gets added again when by the css.

**CSS**

```
elem. {
    width: 20px;
    transition, width 2s;
    animation: myanimation 2s 1; <- this playes first
}

elem:hover {
    //transitioned property's here
    width: 10px;
    //Remove animation for replay
    animation: none;
}

@keyframe {
    //your animation propertys etc.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matijamrkaic/oLendopu/5/) with the functionality. It's done with the keyframe animation.

Important part of the code:

```
.arrow i {

    /* animate initial appearance and whenever state returns to normal from :hover */
    -webkit-animation: translate-left-in 0.3s 1 cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
     animation: translate-left-in 0.3s 1 cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

.arrow:hover i {

    /* animate on hover */
    -webkit-animation: translate-left-out 0.3s 1 cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    animation: translate-left-out 0.3s 1 cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);

    /* Keep the state after the animation has finished */
    -webkit-transform:translateX(30px);
    transform:translateX(30px);
}

/* Keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes translate-left-in {
    0%   { -webkit-transform:translateX(-30px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform:translateX(0); }
}
@keyframes translate-left-in {
    0%   { transform:translateX(-30px); }
    100% { transform:translateX(0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes translate-left-out {
    0%   { -webkit-transform:translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform:translateX(30px); }
}
@keyframes translate-left-out {
    0%   { transform:translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform:translateX(30px); }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, why don't you add more explaining of why you use two animations and why the cubic-bezier curve is used?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with jQuery pretty easy.

Styles:

```
.arrow {
     width: 30px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-left: 50px;
     position: relative;
}
i.fa {
     width: 30px;
     height: auto;
     display: block;
     font-size: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.fa-angle-right', function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '30px'}, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left','-31px');
    });
});
$('body').on('mouseout', '.fa-angle-right', function() {
   $(this).animate({left: '0'}, 500);
});
```

If you absolute position your child <i> inside your parent (.arrow), you can utilize the overflow: hidden and left styles via jQuery to achieve your goal. Since you have given the parent (.arrow) an overflow of hidden, you can animate the <i> to slide out of bounds. Once that animation is complete, you can change the absolute positioning (the left style) of the <i> to return to the start position (to the right of the parent and hidden because of overflow: hidden). Then simply animate the <i> to slide back into bounds.

Comment: I like this answer. But why are you explaining so little of what you actually do here? Lots of room for improvement

Comment: @Persijn - You're right. It didn't occur to me to give details. Will edit.

Comment: Good solution, but, I prefer to go with CSS solution when possible.